# how to watch correlations values in LoadRunner?

Tags: debugging, loadrunner

For whom using LoadRunner VuGen, I want to ask about how to watch the correlation and variables values during running the script. 
I tried putting the correlation in "add to watch" but it gives me an "incorrect expression" and unable to evaluate it and I also tried the "RunTimeData" but the correlation I want doesnt not appear in the list of parameters. 
is there any way to debug and watch variables and correlations values during run ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try expanding the logging to include parameter substitution. In Vugen if you go to:
'Run-time Settings > Log' and enable logging, then click on:
'Always send messages > Extended log > Parameter substitution'

With this setting in place as the log file writes during the script replay you can see each parameter value as it populates highlighted in blue. It's not very elegant as you watch it replay live, but easy to review after the script execution. You have a full log of each parameter and its value whether pulled from the parameter list or built dynamically in the code.

Comment: This works in the log, but not in the watch window for the debugger AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

try below one 
Run-time Settings > Log' and enable logging, then click on: 'Always send messages > Extended log > Parameter substitution'